# Problems after installing spf13-vim

Tags: vim

I've just installed spf13-vim. It is a vim distribution with curated plugins and resources, and I am very satisfied with much of it. Still, after my install, whenever I run vim from the command line I get `CSApprox needs gui support - not loading.
  See :help |csapprox-+gui| for possible workarounds.`

After I get into vim, typing `:help |csapprox-+gui|` as an ex command does not work. I'm stuck!

Comment: So you installed a large plugin distribution that comes with lots of things you don't need or don't even know about. If you are new to Vim you should drop SPF13 as soon as possible and learn how to customize your environment yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Have you tried using sp 13?

Comment: No. I have a carefully crafted config that does everything I need/want so I don't need such a distribution. But I've looked at the code and tried to troobleshoot too many spf13/janus/yadr issues (here and elsewhere) to keep even a shred of respect for the morons who market the hell out of their bullshit personal config toward unsuspecting newbies. Assuming you are a newcomer, starting with an empty `~/.vimrc` and building up from there is the best possible strategy. It's not the quickest, of course, but it's the only one that will pay in the long run.

Comment: I am starting to really like the spf distribution. You have inspired me to look at the .vimrc for the distribution, and I can read it and understand it. I did know about many of the addons they include, especially the one's by tpope and the easy tags. I like spf but it is important to look at what you need and don't need. I took out some packages. No .vimrc from scratch for me at this moment. I don't have time and everyone in my shop is using Eclipse

Comment: Then why don't you stick with Eclipse until you get really comfortable with Vim? Switching to Vim is not necessarily a binary move, you know? When I started using Vim, I kept using TextMate as my main editor for a good 3 or 4 months until I felt confident enough to do the actual switch. By that time, my configuration was very close to what it is now, two years after. Don't rush it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to type `:help csapprox-+gui`. No pipes...

Comment: To help the next guy in your position, you should submit a pull request to fix the error message at https://github.com/godlygeek/csapprox/blob/master/plugin/CSApprox.vim#L64